# Trying to stop going to the next activity in a while with the code "break()". Why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stop the user if the input is lower than 18 to go to the next Activity. I tried this by making a "break()" statement. Doesn't work.
Most of the time it even crashes. I am new in Java and would appreciate if the new code you are giving would be explained very good.

Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
public class AirPortActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nameTextView;
    private EditText inputNumberAge;

    private Button nextActivityButton;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.optionsButton:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_air_port);

        nameTextView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameeditText);
        inputNumberAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputNumberAge);

        nextActivityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivityButton);

        nextActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int number = 18;
               int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString());
               int numberoferror = 18;

              while (parsedInt < numberoferror) {
                  break;
              }

              String nameOfUser = nameTextView.getText().toString();
              int numberAge = 18;

              startStory(nameOfUser);
              String nameOfUserToast = "Hi " + nameOfUser;
              Toast.makeText(AirPortActivity.this, nameOfUserToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

      });
  };

  private void startStory(String nameOfUser) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, AirPortSetup.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (parsedInt < numberoferror) {
  break;
}
```

That will either exit immediately doing nothing, or go into an infinite loop that will never exit. I don't think either is what you want.   If you want to not execute the rest of the function if parsedInt < 18, you want:

```
if(parsedInt < numberoferror) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: @CalebSeeling this doesn't solve your crash issue, if the user leaves the field empty or delete it, it is going to crash, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.optionsButton:
        return false; // or maybe true?
}
```

All `break` does is exit the `switch` block, which an empty statement would have done. `return` exits the function immediately.

Also, `while (parsedInt < numberoferror) { break;}` will either loop forever, or exit on the 1st iteration. Should you use an `if` statement instead, again with a `return` rather than a `break`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the user going to next activity you need to implement your `onClickListener` like this.

```
nextActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       int number = 18;
       int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString());
       int numberoferror = 18;

      if (parsedInt < numberoferror) {
          return;
      }

      String nameOfUser = nameTextView.getText().toString();
      int numberAge = 18;

      startStory(nameOfUser);
      String nameOfUserToast = "Hi " + nameOfUser;
      Toast.makeText(AirPortActivity.this, nameOfUserToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Because if the `parsedInt` is greater than `numberoferror`, then the loop will never be executed and if the `numberoferror` is greater then `parsedInt` then the loop will run infinite times.

You need to replace your while loop with an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your control flow. The break is a way to do it, but is more easy to understand using a condition. If the condition is met, then you go to the next activity, else you have to tell the user about it, or don't move.

The other problem is, parsing a number in Java can crash because the format is not correct, fix that using a try/catch in that operation

```
nextActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String inputValue = inputNumberAge.getText().toString();
               try {
                  final int limit = 18;
                  int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
                  if (limit >= userNumber) {
                     //HERE GO TO NEXT ACTIVITY
                  }
               } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                  //TOAST
               }
          }

      });
```